# NSFetchRequest by date

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode6

I have the method below which i pass NSDate() to get all the results from today. I've trying to get the results by midnight to midnight but it doesnt seem to work. I've noticed that my predicate outputs like this:

"date >= CAST(460249200.000000, "NSDate") AND date <= CAST(460289100.000000, "NSDate")" i presumed that 460249200.000000 is a unix timestamp but if i look at this the day is correct but the year is 1984?

```
func GetAll(dayOfRecords: NSDate) -> NSArray {


    var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: dayOfRecords);
    var midnightComponents = NSDateComponents();
    midnightComponents.day = components.day;
    midnightComponents.month = components.month;
    midnightComponents.year = 2015;
    midnightComponents.hour = 0;

    var midnightDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(midnightComponents);

    var twentyFourHoursLater = NSDateComponents();
    twentyFourHoursLater.day = components.day;
    twentyFourHoursLater.month = components.month;
    twentyFourHoursLater.year = 2015;
    twentyFourHoursLater.hour = 11;
    twentyFourHoursLater.minute = 59;

    var twentyFourHoursAhead = calendar.dateFromComponents(twentyFourHoursLater);


    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", midnightDate!, twentyFourHoursAhead!);
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Movement")
    //filter seems to get 1987!!!??? fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
    var results:NSArray = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)!

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Date properties, Core Data stores the number of seconds since
1 January 2001, GMT in the SQLite database, i.e. what the `NSDate`
property `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` returns.

With

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 460249200.0)
```

you can verify that the first timestamp in the SQLite query is
`2015-08-02 23:00:00 +0000`, which is `2015-08-03 00:00:00` in the
GMT+1 time zone.

So your start date is correctly set to midnight on August 3.
The end date however is set to the same day at 11:59, which is
(approximately) noon and not 24 hours later. You may want to set it
to 23:59, or better to 00:00 at the following day.

This can be simplified to

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let startDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(dayOfRecords)
let endDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: startDate, options: nil)!

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(date >= %@) AND (date < %@)", startDate, endDate);
```